# Php function return is an empty array using Ajax otherwise not

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP framework. My problem is that when I print a php function then it gives me an array with a lot of members but when using the same function with Ajax then the response is empty.

Ajax response function:

```
public function functionOne(){

    $this->autoRender = false;

    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        if(!$this->request->data['amount']) {
            $json['errors'][] = 'Fill in all the required fields';
        }elseif(!is_numeric($this->request->data['amount'])){
            $json['errors'][] = 'Field amound has to be a number';
        }
        if(!$this->request->data['currency_from']){
            $json['errors'][] = 'Fill in all the required fields';
        }
        if(!$this->request->data['currency_to']){
            $json['errors'][] = 'Fill in all the required fields';
        }
        if(!$this->request->data['rate_date']){
            $json['errors'][] = 'Fill in all the required fields';
        }
        if(isset($json['errors'])){
            $json['status'] = 'error';
        }else{
            $json['status'] = 'success';

            $json['curs'] = $this->functionTwo($this->request->data['date1']);
            $json['rates'] = $this->functionThree($this->request->data['date'], $this->request->data['from'], $this->request->data['to'], $this->request->data['amount']);
        }

        print_r(json_encode($json));

    }

}
```

View file ajax request:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#converter').on('submit', function(e) {
            var form = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array(
                        "controller" => "cur",
                                "action" => "functionOne"
                        ));
                        ?>',
                data: form.serialize(),
                type: 'post',
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    var json = data;
                    if (json.status == 'error') {
                        $('#errors').show();
                        $('#currencies').hide();
                        $('#errors').html('');
                        $.each(json.errors, function (k, v) {
                            $('#errors').append("<span>" + v + "</span>");
                        });
                    }
                    if (json.status == 'success') {
                        var json = data;
                        $('#errors').hide();
                        $('#currencies').show();
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    });
```

getCur method returns an array in format "code" => "name". It gets the currencies from reading different sources XML files. When I print the function outside of the response it gives me a correct result but with ajax it just gives me an empty array.

Errors are coming through the response though.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the ajax request success? Check network tab(chrome)

Comment: have you tried to 'echo $json' ??

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali Yes I get to success. When status equals to "success" response is {"status":"success","currencies":[],"currencyRates":[]} and if status equals to "error" then it gives me json full of errors

Comment: @rafat Yes above are the outputs as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was that I created the instances inside the method so ajax thought that I did not have any.

Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Cake are you using??
Depends on the version of cake.

```
1.3.x:

$this->RequestHandler->isAjax();
2.x

$this->request->is('ajax');
```

Also can you check your chrome network tab for any specific issue.

Comment: As mentioned on top of my post CakePHP 2.7 so it's 2.x. Well I've checked the tab and there seems to be no issue, just an empty response :
{"status":"success","currencies":[],"currencyRates":[]}

Comment: @FickDace If the above is true you seem to be focussing on the wrong problem. The unshown methods getCurrency and getCurrencyRate are returning empty arrays - you should be asking and debugging why that's the case.

Comment: @AD7six sorry for wrong wording. I'm kind of out of ideas because when I print the function out in php it works, but when using the same function through ajax request - the response is empty. Any tips maybe ?

Thank you!

Comment: If the problem is your unshown functions _show and debug those functions_. That's not [the normal way to render json](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key) btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try to :

1. echo your json like `echo json_encode($json);`
2. In success callback, parse data variable by using :

   ```
   success : function(data){
     var json = $.parseJSON(data);
     console.log(json);
   }
   ```

   See the data inside console.

Comment: If that's the "fix" the problem is the headers of the response - and that's what should change. The OP has effectively said several times though that the response is valid but empty... misleading if not the case.

Comment: Console gives:   

Object {status: "success", currencies: Array[0], currencyRates: Array[0]} currencies: Array[0] length: 0 proto: Array[0] currencyRates: Array[0] status: "success"